# Ativar módulo "zlib" no php 5.5

Tags: php, linux, servidor, magento, centos

Tenho uma loja Magento hospedada em um server dedicado e para gerar um arquivo PDF em um dos módulos da plataforma é necessário ter instalado a extensão Zlib. A mesma já está instalada, se eu executar o seguinte comando no terminal a extensão aparece na listagem:

> php -m

Porém se ao executar o seguinte comando, ele mostra que o tal módulo está desativado:

> php -i

Dentre as informações apresentadas, temos isto:

> Directive => Local Value => Master Value zlib.output_compression =>
> Off => Off
>
> zlib.output_compression_level => -1 => -1
>
> zlib.output_handler => no value => no value

Adicionei "zlib.output_compression = On" no php.ini porém nada mudou.

No manual do PHP diz "Você precisa configurar o PHP com --with-zlib[=DIR]", porém eu não tenho ideia de onde rodar esse código "--with-zlib[=DIR]"

Se alguém puder me ajudar serei muito grato, pois estou procurando por uma solução para isso a dias.

Comment: Tentou reiniciar o servidor? oO

Comment: Conseguiu resolver seu problema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Se for compilado no Ubuntu 16.04 64Bits, segue o script que fiz para o **curso de Hospedagem de Sites com ISPConfig**:
>   https://gist.github.com/jniltinho/959f873a84b72ddd9fca2513a52a6b04

**Instale esses pacotes:**

```
apt-get -y install build-essential libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev 
apt-get -y install libfcgi-dev libfcgi0ldbl libjpeg62-dbg libxml2-dev
apt-get -y install libmcrypt-dev libssl-dev libc-client2007e libc-client2007e-dev
apt-get -y install libbz2-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev libjpeg-dev libpng12-dev 
apt-get -y install libfreetype6-dev libkrb5-dev libpq-dev libicu-devlibxml2-dev libbz2-dev 
apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev libjpeg-dev libicu-dev libxml2-dev
apt-get install libpng12-dev libfreetype6-dev libkrb5-dev libpq-dev libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev
```

Comment: Bem vindo Nilton OS. Para que a resposta fique mais completa, além do link, coloque seu script na resposta. Quando possível faça também o [tour] do site e conheça melhor a comunidade. :)

Answer (score 1):

Assumindo que você passou a ter este problema por usar o PHP 7.0, então você deve instalar o seguinte pacote:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-zip
```

Outra dica é que se você quiser saber todas as bibliotecas disponiveis para o PHP, use o comando:

```
sudo apt-cache search php7.0-*
```

Isto deve resolver seu problema, (assumi que você esteja usando Debian ou Ubuntu)